# Unable to access AJAX JSON response, despite setting content type and datatype, parseJSON returns error however still 'valid' JSON

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4 as a backend (though I don't think it is necessarily causing an issue here), and am trying to do some AJAX validation (to preserve dynamically populated dropdowns).

First of all, the code I am using to call the AJAX request:

```
$('#add_character_submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ URL::route("addcharactercheck") }}',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'name': $('#name').val().replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\-\(\)\.\,]+/', ''),
            'gender': $('#gender').val().replace('/[^0-9]+/', ''),
            'server': $('#server').val().replace('/[^0-9]+/', ''),
            'faction': $('#faction').val().replace('/[^0-9]+/', ''),
            'race': $('#race').val().replace('/[^0-9]+/', ''),
            'class': $('#class').val().replace('/[^0-9]+/', ''),
            'path': $('#path').val().replace('/[^0-9]+/', '')
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function(response) {
        console.log(response.errors);
    });
});
```

And then this is the response I am getting:

```
{"success":false,"errors":{"name":["Please pick a name"],"server":["Please pick a server"],"faction":["Please pick a faction"],"race":["Please pick a race"],"class":["Please pick a class"],"path":["Please pick a path"]}}
```

If I put that into a JSON validator, it says it passes.

I am returning the response as `Content-Type: application/json` and I have `dataType: 'json'` in the AJAX request as above, however trying to `console.log(response.errors)` results in `undefined`.

I have also tried using `$.parseJSON` on the response, however that gives an `unexpected character` type error (note this is just to double check).

If I type the following in the console:

```
var x = {"success":false,"errors":{"name":["That name is not available"],"faction":["Please pick a faction"],"race":["Please pick a race"],"class":["Please pick a class"],"path":["Please pick a path"]}}
console.log(x.errors);
```

Then it correctly outputs the errors in the console.

Despite searching a good dozen or so similar questions here on SO, they all seem to suggest an accepted answer of one or both of the above - I can't find anything different to try.

Comment: If you're getting valid JSON and the dataType is set to JSON, it's automatically parsed into an object, and trying to parse it again will give an error? You can see in the console if it's an object, and it's not really clear what the problem is here ?

Comment: As you can see from the code, all I'm doing is `console.log(response.errors);` and that is giving me an `undefined` message in Firebug's console. If in the console I type var x = thejsonstring and then console.log(x.errors) it works

Comment: The response object only exists within the fail closure scope. When you do a console.log from Firebug's console, it only looks in the window scope.

Comment: @Rory, just trying to demonstrate that AFAICT the JSON returned is valid. The console.log I'm using within the fail closure is what is outputting undefined.

Comment: jQuery seems to return a jqXHR object, instead of data, when failing. Try just logging response, not response.errors, and see what it is (as @adeneo suggested). http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Rory, ah hah, that was the problem. .fail closure doesn't return a data object. I had to do: `var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);` and then I can do `console.log(json.errors);` Feel free to write as answer @Rory and I will mark as accepted, thanks a lot!

Comment: @JamesVassie added it as answer

Answer (score 1):

The right answer was established in the comments:

On `.fail`, jQuery returns a jqXHR object, instead of data. The data you're looking for is in the `responseText` property of this object.

```
.fail(function(jqXHR) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
    console.log(json);
});
```